# Compare two columns in a data frame and give specific value from another column if the values aren't same

Tags: python, pandas

[image: example]

I want to compare column_3 to column_1.
If the value is the same give the value from column_2 back, if not search for the same value in column_1 and give the value from column_2. The output should be like column_4.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! There are a number of ways to do this using pandas or numpy functions. It would be helpful if you could insert the approach you have tried with the given example data.

Answer (score 0):

You could apply a Series map function to `column_3` using a dictionary with keys from `column_1` and corresponding values in `column_2`. This will then act as a lookup for values in `column_3` and create a new column, `column_4`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'column_1':[5,6,7,8,9], 
                   'column_2':[435,345,765,876,987], 
                   'column_3':[5,6,7,5,6]})

df['column_4'] = df['column_3'].map({k:v for k,v in zip(df['column_1'],df['column_2'])})


#    column_1   column_2    column_3    column_4
# 0    5          435          5          435
# 1    6          345          6          345
# 2    7          765          7          765
# 3    8          876          5          435
# 4    9          987          6          345
```